# XmlElement.Order get ignored while serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, c#-2.0

For this data model, the order is completly ignored:

```
[XmlType("person")]
public sealed class Person {
    private string name;
    [XmlElement("name", Order = 0)]
    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("children", Order = 1)]  
    public Child[] Children = new Child[1];
}

[XmlType("child")]
public sealed class Child {
    private string name;
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

Please notice the *Order* arguments.

Here is the serialization class:

```
public sealed class PersonPersistence {
    private static readonly XmlSerializer SERIALIZER;
    private static readonly XmlWriterSettings WRITER_SETTINGS;
    private static readonly XmlSerializerNamespaces XML_NAMESPACE;

    static PersonPersistence() {
        SERIALIZER = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

        WRITER_SETTINGS = new XmlWriterSettings();
        WRITER_SETTINGS.IndentChars = "  "; // two spaces
        WRITER_SETTINGS.Indent = true;
        WRITER_SETTINGS.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        // omit namespaces
        XML_NAMESPACE = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XML_NAMESPACE.Add("", "");
    }

    public static void SaveFile(Person model, string filename) {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, WRITER_SETTINGS)) {
            SERIALIZER.Serialize(writer, model, XML_NAMESPACE);
        }
    }
}
```

And an example:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "John Doe";
person.Children[0] = new Child();
person.Children[0].Name = "Alice";
PersonPersistence.SaveFile(person, "foo.xml");
```

The **actual output** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person>
  <children>
    <child>
      <name>Alice</name>
    </child>
  </children>
  <name>John Doe</name>
</person>
```

The **expected output** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <children>
    <child>
      <name>Alice</name>
    </child>
  </children>
</person>
```

Please notice, I like to have the *name* **before** the *children* element.

Comment: [Works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMv8Pv) as far as I can tell. Can't reproduce.

Comment: @Charles-Mager you are right, I've test this code in a separate project with .NET 4.5 and it works as expected. The problem occurs while running it with .NET 2.0, more precisely in Unity's Mono platform. So it may be a bug of Mono.